# How to enable hardware acceleration with the Radeon HD 7870?

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, graphics

Any idea on how to do this? The open source driver does not do this,  and the 2 propriety drivers (fglrx and fglrx-updates) both cause my computer to refuse to boot up.

The output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` is:

```
Not software rendered: no
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes

Unity 3D supported: no
```

The lack of hardware acceleration has made my computer pretty much unusable, it runs minecraft a 6 fps...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please specify the Ubuntu release version and Unity version, because it is version-specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could try installing the latest drivers from AMD directly, here is the link:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Comment: Hint: This is not an useful answer, it is just a link. Add information why this is a solution and how to apply the solution to make it an useful answer.

Comment: I've already tried this, did the same thing as installing the driver through the "Software and Updates" section. Any other ideas?